# How to resolve TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, event-handling

Having trouble trying to make my button route to a new component when it's clicked. I've read the react router docs and went through stack overflow and figured I would try putting `this.props.history.push("/")` in my `handleClick()` but when I click the button I get a reading 'push' type error. I also tried another solution in the router docs about importing { withRouter } but that doesn't seem to work either.

**App.js:**

```
    import React, {Component} from "react"
    import fbook from "./image/fbook.png"
    import roller from "./image/roller2.png"
    import tweet from "./image/tweet.png"
    import insta from "./image/insta.png"
    import Buy from "./Shop.js"
    import Test from "./Store.js"
    import { BrowserRouter as Route, Router, Link, withRouter  } from "react-router-dom";
    
    
    /*function Yup() {
      const [navigate] = useNavigate()
      return (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Test} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      );
    }*/
    
    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          isNewWindow: false,
          values: [
            {id: 1, name: 'Specs'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Designs'},
            {id: 3, name: 'Shops'},
            {id: 4, name: 'Warranty'},
          ]
        }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.closeWindowPortal = this.closeWindowPortal.bind(this)

  

    }
    
      
    
      componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
          this.closeWindowPortal();
        });
      }

    handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value} = event.target

    this.setState({ [name]: value })
  

    }
    
      handleClick() {
        this.props.history.push("/");  
      }
    
      closeWindowPortal() {
        this.setState({ isNewWindow: false })
      }
    
      
    
      render() {
        let optionTemplate = this.state.values.map(v => (
          <option value={v.id}>{v.name}

</option>
    ));

   
   

    return (
      
      <body>
        <header>
          <h2>GAMING</h2>
          <div className="nav">
            <a href="#">STUFF</a>
            <a href="#">DESIGNS</a>
            <a href="#">MODS</a>
            <a href="#">GRIPS</a>
          </div>

          <div className="drop">
            <label>
              <div id="menu">
                MENU
              </div>

              <select className="box" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                {optionTemplate}
              </select>
            </label>

          </div>
        </header>

        <img src={roller} className="roller" alt="controller" />

        <div className="container">

          <h1>ONLY FOR THE PROS</h1><hr/>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>ORDER NOW</button>
            
            <Route path="/" component={Test} />
                
              
            

            
            

          {this.state.isNewWindow && (
            <Buy closeWindowPortal = {this.closeWindowPortal} >
              <Test />
             <button onClick={this.closeWindowPortal}></button>
            </Buy>
          )}

        </div> 
          

        
            <footer>
              <div className="socials">
                <img src={insta} className="insta" alt="Instagram" />
                <img src={tweet} className="tweet" alt="Twitter"/>
                <img src={fbook} className="fbook" alt="Facebook"/>
              </div>

              <p>© 2021, Designed by A.H. </p>
            </footer> 
      </body>
      
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';





ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: For starters, you are importing `BrowserRouter` and renaming it to `Route`, and importing the root `Router`, so this isn't helping you. Can you verify what version of `react-router-dom` you have installed? From your project directory, run `npm list react-router react-router-dom`.

Comment: currently running version: (react-router-dom@6.0.2) and (react-router@6.0.2)

Comment: RRDv6 no longer exports a `withRouter` HOC nor does it inject route props or use a `history` object directly. Convert to a function component use the `useNavigate` hook.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied any props to your `<App />` component, thus `this.props.history` is undefined. Nowhere in your code have you actually wired up react router or anything else that would supply a `history` prop to your `<App />` component.

You either need to wrap your component with the HoC that react router provides or leverage their hook which does the same (though to use the hook you would need to convert from a class component to a function component).

Comment: If I were to look in the react router-docs where would I look to find a solution? I've already read over the docs multiple times. Thanks for the help.